# How do I integrate this double integral?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

$\iint_D \,(x+y)^2 e^{x-y} \,\,dxdy $

Where D is the region bounded by : 
$ x+y=1, \\ x+y=4, \\ x-y=-1 \\ x-y=1 $

I've tried to use $ x=r\cos(\theta) $ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ but I haven't really got anywhere, how should I go about this?

Comment: Let $u=x+y,v=x-y$!

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? this appears to be more of a series of integrations by parts.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=x+y,v=x-y$, then 
$$\frac{D(x,y)}{D(u,v)}=-1/2.$$
$$\iint_D \,(x+y)^2 e^{x-y} \,\,dxdy=\iint_{D_1} \,u^2 e^{v} \,\,\left|\frac{D(x,y)}{D(u,v)}\right|dudv$$
$$=1/2\iint_{D_1} \,u^2 e^{v} \,\,dudv=1/2\int_{1}^4u^2 du\int_{-1}^1 e^v dv
=21/2(e-e^{-1}).$$
Here $D_1=[1,4]\times[-1,1]$.